# Truing rear wheel with gears cassette

Tags: wheel-truing

I have a 700cc rear wheel with gear cassette. The centering or dish of the wheel appears to balance towards the gear cassette. This means when i use a tool like the below image, that the hub (and the hub lock nuts) is not in the centre. Should I be truing the rear wheel to be centered on the dish or is it off-set towards the gear cassette for a reason?

[image]

Comment: A standard rear wheel should be symmetrical, with the axle sticking out the same amount on both sides.  (NB: This will make the spokes non-symmetrical.)  A newly built wheel will not "want" to do this right, but care taken in truing will bring it about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You rim should be centered over your hub. If you are using the tool correctly, and the rim is not centered, it should be redished.

If you are not confident in your abilities and knowledge on the subject, get a second opinion from your LBS mechanic before you make changes to the wheel. Sometimes, those kind of changes are difficult to reverse.

Comment: This video states that the rim is centered between the two lock nuts and centering the rim on the hub. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-1n--L8Pjs&feature=player_detailpage#t=143s

Comment: Yes. That's what I said. Your rim should be centered on your hub. By definition, if your rim is centered on the hub, it is centered between the locknuts. I'm not sure what you are commenting on....

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you take the quick release skewer out before you use that tool, don't use it EXACTLY like the picture.

You should center it on the dish.